# nosetests import error for existing installed module

Tags: python, nosetests

Trying to add nose tests to an existing project. The class being tested has dependencies, which in turn depend on another module in our code base (let's call it *extern_module*), in a separate project.

I installed *extern_module* using its setup.py. I can import it if I open a python shell.

When I try to run my test, however, I'm told that *extern_module* is not found. I'm too new to Python to say I have the whole import mechanism down - why would a module that I can import from the Python shell not be available elsewhere?

**EDIT**

Turns out the issue is with importing *extern_module.submodule*. If I change the dependency of my test class to import *extern_module* only, things seem fine.

My test package is built so:

```
tests
 - __init__.py
 - specific_test_package
   - __init__.py
   - mytest.py
```

And I run this by navigating to tests/specific_test_package, and typing `nosetests mytest.py`

Thanks!